# Probably of guessing a 4-digit number

Tags: probability

A credit card company sent me a notice that said, "we will randomly generate a 4-digit pin for you.

I thought to myself, "I guess the pin will be 3456". When the randomly generated pin came in the mail later that week it was indeed 3456!

So, my question is: what is the probability of this occurring? I know the probability of guessing a 4-digit pin, but wouldn't I then also have to multiply that probability by the probability that the random-number generator would generate the number I guessed?

Thank you.

Comment: Let's simplify. I tell you that I've written down a 1 digit number (0, 1, 2, ..., 9), chosen uniformly at random. What's the probability that you guess that digit? Why?